# Quiver basemap plot - how to make the quiver density latitude-dependent?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to do a quiver plot on a polar basemap plot. I have a regular lat/lon grid, and because there are more grid boxes at the higher latitudes, my code plots as many quivers at the pole as on the equator, so they overlap etc. How can I make the density of quivers latitude-dependent?

This is the code I use

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, addcyclic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


m_mu = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=10,lon_0=0,resolution='l',round=True)

lats=np.arange(0.,91.,15.)
lons=np.arange(-180.,181.,30.)
valin_u=np.array([[np.random.randn() for y in range(len(lons))] for x in range(len(lats))])
valin_v=np.array([[np.random.randn() for y in range(len(lons))] for x in range(len(lats))])
del x,y

valin = np.sqrt( valin_u**2 + valin_v**2 )

mu_cyclic, lons_cyclic = addcyclic(valin, lons)
mu_cyclic_u, lons_cyclic = addcyclic(valin_u, lons)
mu_cyclic_v, lons_cyclic = addcyclic(valin_v, lons)

grid = np.meshgrid( lons_cyclic, lats )
x, y = m_mu( *grid)

plt.figure()
cs = m_mu.pcolormesh(x, y, mu_cyclic)
csquiv = m_mu.quiver(x[::1,::1], y[::1,::1], mu_cyclic_u[::1,::1], mu_cyclic_v[::1,::1])
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

I guess I could write a function to set a latitude-dependent number of the values to .nan, but hopefully there is a better solution?

Many thanks for your help :-)
Sabine